# Как узнать URL перенаправленного сайта?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ссылка - https://avia.tickets.ua/m/preloader/MOWNYC14.06.20220/1%7C0%7C0%7CA, которая через некоторое время перенаправляет нас на второй сайт с ссылкой на подобии такой - https://avia.tickets.ua/m/search/results?session_id=de7612cfb43c32b8acc7e33709e2218d

Как мне програмно вывести из первой ссылки вторую?

Comment: Ну поскольку там загрузка идёт, наверное через Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Берёшь код страницы, смотришь как там реализовано перенаправление (через заголовок в `head`) или скриптом. Потом пишешь парсер, который находит адрес второй страницы из ответа на первую ссылку.

Answer (score 0):

POST запрос https://avia.tickets.ua/m/search/directions%5Bfrom_name%5D%5B0%5D=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C+%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81i%D1%8F&directions%5Bfrom_code%5D%5B0%5D=MOW&directions%5Bto_name%5D%5B0%5D=%D0%9D%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%2C+%D0%A1%D0%A8%D0%90&directions%5Bto_code%5D%5B0%5D=NYC&directions%5Bdeparture_date%5D%5B0%5D=14.06.2022&directions%5Bplus_minus%5D%5B0%5D=0&class=A&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&promo=&rooms=1&start_from_hotel=1&original_search_source%5Boriginal_search_source%5D=UNKNOWN&original_search_source%5Boriginal_request_time%5D=&original_search_source%5Boriginal_session%5D= в ответ JSON в нем есть ключ session_id=...